# How to work with German umlaut characters in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, python-3.6

I have a text file with German phrases in it, and I am trying to remove non alphabetic characters, without removing umlaut characters. I have seen other similar questions already, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Python seems to consider umlaut characters to be two characters in some cases, but the print function works fine:

```
>>> ch = '\xc3\xbc'
>>> print(ch)
ü
>>> print(len(ch))
2
>>> print(list(ch))
['\xc3', '\xbc']
```

my code to remove non alphabetical characters is

```
import unicodedata
def strip_po(s):
    ''.join(x for x in s if unicodedata.category(x) != 'Po')
word = strip_po(word)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ed/Desktop/Deutsch/test", line 17, in <module>
  word = strip_po(word)
File "/home/ed/Desktop/Deutsch/test", line 9, in strip_po
  ''.join(x for x in s if unicodedata.category(x) != 'Po')
File "/home/ed/Desktop/Deutsch/test", line 9, in <genexpr>
  ''.join(x for x in s if unicodedata.category(x) != 'Po')
TypeError: category() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: Wherefrom do you get the strings?

Comment: Are you sure you are running it on Python 3?

Comment: The "unicode, not str" bit of the error message implies you're using Python 2, but you've tagged this question as Python 3.  Which one are you actually using?  Unicode handling differs significantly between the two versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using Python2 in this scenario because I can recreate your issue with Py2.

You don't want to be doing any text processing with bytes. The Python 2 `str` type is actually just a byte list, which is why len is saying your character is 2 bytes long. You want to turn those bytes into a `unicode` type. You can do that like so:

```
In [1]: '\xc3\xbc'.decode('utf8')
Out[1]: u'\xfc'
```

Note running `len` on that will yield 1, since it's now just one unicode character. Now you can process your text normally, and that character:
`unicodedata.category(u'\xfc')` is of category `'Ll'`

You probably want to hide more categories than just `Po`. There is a full list here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property

Python's built-in `isalpha` method may help you here, but you want the type to be `unicode` first as shown above.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

```
In [2]: u'\xfc'.isalpha()
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: Yup, turns out I was accidentally using python2. I'm using atom text editor to code it, and a package so I can run the code by pressing f5. I thought that was running it using python 3, but its using python 2 so that's my answer. Thank you